# Monitor and capture active session details on Zenoss about remote vm via snmp/WMI or on linux screen/ssh session/w etc.

Tags: linux, session, ssh, monitor, zenoss

I found many ways to figured it out on my own.
Here is few details:

> I am able to save user login details on that remote machine.
>   but the issue is not to capture but get notified for that activity.
>   I want to right down script get that details and send it to other database server that can be seen on webui {monitoring screen}
>   researchers may have that done before but its a finding needle in wool.
>   I got right direction in starting and start writing for it.
>   no result.
>
> ## Any one have idea, from where to start?????

Any tool,source code can be helpful to handle this type activity and put all ideas on screen.
thanks

Comment: Do you want to be notified immediately or within monitoring cycle (default Zenoss 5 minutes)?
Do you need to track login as number (one login now) or do you need track also some metadata (one login of user U now)?

Comment: Hi  I was expecting you @JanGaraJ  I am about to track it like,what we are getting in cpu monitor graphs. or may be at list get instant alert that you logged in here.

Comment: As we can set trigger and get that notification response so quickly,,, that would be more than enough...you got me correctly ...have any chances to go with for me??

Answer (score 0):

1.) standard monitoring

Expose required metrics through SNMP e.g. http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Tut:Extending_snmpd_using_shell_scripts
and use standard Zenoss SNMP monitoring (graphs, thresholds, triggers, notifications). Probably also WMI provides similar extend functionality.

2.) instant notification

Generate trap, when login happened and send it to Zenoss - it will create event in Zenoss (it's not real metric, it's only event)